# How to edit startup applications in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did the startup-applications-preferences program go?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159887/where-did-the-startup-applications-preferences-program-go)

In Ubuntu 12.10 I can't find the app for editing the list of applications anymore? Where has it gone and how can I reinstall it? I don't even find a fitting entry in Synaptic.

Comment: Already answered at : http://askubuntu.com/questions/159887/where-did-the-startup-applications-preferences-program-go

Comment: sorry, didn't see that.

Comment: Also have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically

Comment: I was confused because I simply didn't think about using the application specific part in the dash. I used the default one ("home" or something), and there the app didn't turn up.