# Chrome automatically starts on boot while using xfce

Tags: 13.04, xfce

As I said in title, when I boot my PC and after system loads, Chrome starts automatically. I checked in startup application, and I couldn't find Chrome entry. Can anyone tell me why Chrome starts automatically and how to stop it. I'm using XUbuntu 13.04

Comment: It shouldn't start automatically; check for desktop files in `~/.config/autostart` and `/etc/xdg/autostart`.

Comment: There is no Chrome in those folders and still Chrome starts automatically

Comment: have you tryed Startup Application this could help http://askubuntu.com/questions/159887/where-did-the-startup-applications-preferences-program-go and this http://askubuntu.com/questions/69810/how-do-i-add-remove-the-hidden-startup-applications

Comment: Yes, I tried Startup Application from xfce and gnome, but I can't find nowhere Chrome. Xfce has option to save session on shut down, I remember I activated that option once, but since that option was useless for me I deactivated it. Maybe Chrome stuck there while that option was activated.

Comment: Look in ~/.cache/sessions

Comment: Well, I have bunch of files here, but they all start with xfce... I don't know where to look.

Comment: I have the identical problem, and there is nothing related to chrome in ~/.config/autostart or /etc/xdg/autostart. It just suddenly started happening last week. I have found a line saying Legacy0_Command=chromium-browser in ~/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-{myhostname}:0 so I've deleted it and will come back after I have rebooted...

Comment: Yep, that fixed it for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `autostart` settings seem to be clean, I would expect that xfce4-session has cached the app and restores it on boot time.

I suspect that you need to clear up your sessions cache: `Settings Manager, Sessions and Startup, Sessions Tab, Clear Saved Sessions`. Or delete the contents of `~/.cache/sessions`, having logged out first. For details see: [Xubuntu reopens last session applications even though it shouldn't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382331/xubuntu-reopens-last-session-applications-even-though-it-shouldnt).