# Xubuntu reopens last session applications even though it shouldn't

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, session

There's something strange going on with my Xubuntu setup (13.10 at the moment, but I remember having this issue in 13.04 as well, before upgrading). Each time I log in, the system reopens the applications that I didn't close before shutting down the computer last time. This is strange since in the session and startup settings I don't have the `Automatically save session on logout` setting checked. What can I do to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clear your sessions cache: `Settings Manager, Sessions and Startup, Sessions Tab, Clear Saved Sessions`.

Log out and log back in.

Reference: [Xfce Docs » Core » Session Manager » Preferences](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/preferences)

---

Another possibility is to delete the contents of `~/.cache/sessions`. However, you will need to log out first and then open a console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in from the keyboard. Then delete the contents or move the files elsewhere, and close the console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. Now, on logging in via the GUI, you should have a clean session.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't solve the problem

Comment: @misterjinx, see if the edit helps

Comment: I did as you suggested the second time and the problem seems to be fixed. after I logged in there were no apps reopened from the last time. hope this will last. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me long term. Even setting "restart style" to "Never" in "Session and Startup" -> "Session" tab didn't work either - the setting would eventually revert to "If running".

What seems to work so far is adding the following line to /etc/rc.local

> rm -rf /home/*/.cache/sessions/*

before "exit 0", obviously.