# The same windows are opened every time I log in. Can I fix that?

Tags: xubuntu

The same windows appear as I switch on the computer. Like if I had selected "Save session for future logins" though I don't. I remember launching some GUI apps with sudo, can it be the source of the problem?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what UI/windowmanager setup you're currently using.  You indicated xubuntu, which appears to already have been answered at [Xubuntu reopens last session applications even though it shouldn't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382331/xubuntu-reopens-last-session-applications-even-though-it-shouldnt)

If so, please be sure to give that person their updoot.  :D