# Setting up Conky on Ubuntu

Tags: themes, conky, .desktop

[image: conky]

I am surprised after seeing the features in the picture shown. After searching a little bit, I came to know that it is a conky theme. But now I also am not clear about it, and I don't know how to install it. Help me out!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Install Conky in Ubuntu/Linux Mint open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install conky conky-all
```

First of all Download Startup script with following commands:

```
cd && wget -O .start-conky http://goo.gl/6RrEw
chmod +x .start-conky
```

Now open **Startup Applications** > click **Add**  > New Dialog box will open click on **Browse** > Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> see following screenshot.

[image]

**>> Infinity Conky for Ethernet**

To Install Infinity-Conky open Terminal and enter following commands:

```
cd && wget -O infinity-noobslab-eth1.zip http://goo.gl/ZiFbd
unzip infinity-noobslab-eth1.zip && rm infinity-noobslab-eth1.zip
```

**>> Infinity Conky for Wifi**

To Install Infinity-Conky open Terminal and enter following commands:

```
cd && wget -O infinity-noobslab-wlan1.zip http://goo.gl/qkIWg
unzip infinity-noobslab-wlan1.zip && rm infinity-noobslab-wlan1.zip
```

**>> If gadget doesn't fit in your screen,** you can change size in line 43 (minimum_size).
Enter Following command to open file in text editor and change size:

```
nano ~/.conkyrc
```

Comment: Nice , is that image script mentioned in your answer ?

Comment: I think that this answer is not enough , how you are running the script and where are the startup application option in 13.04 need to mention.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159887/where-did-the-startup-applications-preferences-program-go

Comment: All goo.gl links are broken

Answer (score 1):

**Conky** is a system monitor that can display just about anything, either on your root desktop or in its own window.  So, it's not a theme.

You can install it from **Ubuntu Software Center**:

[image: USC]

Or from [**terminal**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) by running next command:

```
sudo apt-get install conky-all
```

More about: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky.

Answer (score 0):

The above users mentioned possible ways and I am also mentioning one more possible way . No worry with scripts and all. simply add this PPA & install conky.

Open your terminal and paste these lines one after one

```
sudo apt-get install conky conky-all
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/noobslab-conky
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install infinity-conky
```

Thats it , it will install conky and you are ready to run it from the menu. after opening that follow the instructions. simple installation.

[Credit goes here](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/06/install-infinity-conky-in-ubuntulinux.html)