# Does any Conky theme make notes like tomboy notes, Xpad visible?

Tags: conky, tomboy

As the title says, are their any themes which display text from tomboy,Xpad or gedit? or is their any file where I can edit to add text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conky` displays whatever you have in your `$HOME/.conkyrc` file. You can add arbirtary text there. Alternatively, you can have it import and display the contents of another file. For example, if you have the text in question in `~/foo.txt`, you can add this line to your `.conkyrc`:

```
 ${exec cat ~/foo.txt}
```

That will run `cat ~/foo.txt` and will display the contents of the file in your `conky`. If the contents of the file can change and you want the changes to be updated in `conky`, use this instead:

```
 ${execi 3 cat ~/foo.txt}
```

That will run `cat ~/foo.txt` every 3 seconds, updating the text displayed by `conky`.

Comment: Not working & by the way, I have two conky themes running at the same time! one when I installed with the help of this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/321018/setting-up-conky-on-ubuntu & I then installed conky-manager for more themes. how to disable first theme?

Comment: @DpN is it working or not? You seem to be accepting/unaccepting this repeatedly and I'm confused. `.conkyrc` is the default `conky` config file, your themes might be using something else. How are you launching `conky`?

Comment: I added with conky manager-->start at boot-->

Comment: @DpN OK, you need to add the commands I gave you to whichever file your themes are using. This is normally `~/.conkyrc` but I don't know which file your themes have chosen. You should be able to figure it out through conky manager (I've never used that, I just write the themes manually). Once you have found the file, add the directives from my answer, **after** `#TEXT`, lines above `#TEXT` are settings and not displayed.

Comment: any specific sites from where i can better understand how to make conky themes?

Comment: @DpN the "themes" are simple text files. Have a look at the docs [here](http://conky.sourceforge.net/documentation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Conky is able to display everything you can get as standard output from any program.
So, I made my own command-line note manager in Python (you can download it from [here](https://github.com/tabuto/pyclinote)).

Once installed, pyclinote can manage your note as simple text.
In order to add and delete notes you can use the gui, by launching this command from the directory you have chosen for pyclinote:

python pyclinote.py -g

Now, to show your notes on conky, you just have to add the following command on your conky.conf:

${execi 2 (cd /your_path/pyclinote-1.0 && python pyclinote.py -s)}

this will execute every 2 seconds the 'python pyclinote.py -s' command that will return your notes list.

In order to make the management of notes more easy, I added a keyboard shortcut to python pyclinote.py -g, so with a simple key combo
I can easily add or delete my notes.

Hope this will help you!

[references](http://b-admin.blogspot.it/2015/04/show-and-manage-notes-on-your-linux.html)