# My computer like Disk Usage Statistics bar in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, windows, disk

Is it possible to view disk usage statistics, like free space left, as in "My Computer" in Windows, but for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ?

Comment: Are you talking about a File Explorer just to look at files & directories, like Nautilus or Thunar? Or a live disk usage indicator, like in a desktop panel or `conky` monitoring program?

Comment: Care explain further please ? Never used Nautilus or Thunar.

Comment: Just checked Thunar and Nautilus. I was just wondering if I could use so shortcut to free space left in each drive.

Comment: There should be plenty like that, if not a full system status program like `conky`, then just a little desktop panel indicator... I'm checking

Comment: added an answer about it & other options too, if if's useful feel free to select/check/vote :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some nice Indicator Applets for Ubuntu, they can display all sorts of info & stats about your system. These should be for Unity, but they often work with other DE's too.

I *really* like **Conky**, it displays on the desktop, (could be transparent to the desktop image) or in a window, and can display just about anything - CPU usage, RAM, individual CPU cores, network up/download, disk read/write, processes, uptime, kernel, sensors/temps/fans...

- [Setting up Conky on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321018/setting-up-conky-on-ubuntu)
- http://conky.sourceforge.net/documentation.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky

This link shows [10 that How-To Geek likes](http://www.howtogeek.com/118908/10-awesome-indicator-applets-for-ubuntus-unity-desktop/). indicator-mulitload might have a free disk space in it (`sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload` or search Software Center)

This question has a few other options too [What can replace system monitoring in the top Gnome Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity)

[Here's a screenshot from the askubuntu Q about Conky, FYI]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Xen2050. Is it possible to get something on Gnome fallback ? I tried Indicator Multiload without success.

Comment: You're welcome. Each DE can be a little different, and there are a lot of DE's (probably too many)... but each one generally has some indicator applets of it's own. Often one will work on different DE's (for example conky needs a few different settings sometimes), but it can be hit & miss for any of them

Comment: indicator-multiload shows read and write speed, but not usage/free space.  Conky is a valid choice.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is **Disk Usage Analyzer**

[image]

Disk Usage Analyzer comes pre-installed with Ubuntu, and allows you to view detailed breakdowns of your disk usage.

It can be launched by searching for **Disk Usage Analyzer** from the Dash, or by using the command `baobab` in the Terminal.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of it. But it takes too much time to load on my system. I was trying to find something similar to Windows 7 + my computer

Comment: @Dilip if you don't expand it to the ring view, `baobab` is quite fast.

Answer (score -1):

Found answer in the form of Cinnamon Desktop Environment. Hope this helps.

[image: cinnamon free space]

As you can see, free space is shown on the bottom bar.

Comment: Your answer would be much improved if you were to [edit] your answer and include a screenshot  showing how this resolved the issue. Thank you

Comment: That's like killing a mosquito with a cannon...  Most users will not want an entire new desktop system just for "free space left"

Comment: @ElderGeek , Screen shot included.

Comment: @Fabby , you are right. Stay with Unity.

Comment: @Fabby I've always been satisfied with Ctrl-Alt-T  `df -h` myself, but this is still a valid answer. Votes will decide how good the community thinks it is, but as long as Dilip is satisfied with his solution......

Comment: This is not expected as an answer. Please post if you find something with respect to Nautilus, not a desktop environment.