# How do I set my startup applications?

Tags: startup-applications

I've looked through old questions like [Where did the startup-applications-preferences program go?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159887/where-did-the-startup-applications-preferences-program-go) but it didn't help me as I searched the software centre for gnome-session-properties and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the dash and type startup, it should show up.