# How do keep the modified Logitech T650 trackpad configuration persistent

Tags: command-line, touchpad, trackpad, logitech, xinput

The most essential features of the Logitech T650 trackpad works right out of the box. However, I was unable to get ‘Natural scrolling’ to work.

After a bit of searching, I was led to [this post by Franklin Strube on configuring the T650](http://franklinstrube.com/blog/logitech-t650-wireless-touchpad-ubuntu/). In the post, Franklin suggests using `xinput` to reconfigure the trackpad.

To invert the scroll axis, I reordered the 4, 5, 6, and 7 buttons to 5, 4, 7 and 6 by entering the following into the terminal.

```
xinput set-button-map "Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4101" 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

This resulted in natural scrolling to work immediately.

Unfortunately, this configuration doesn’t appear to be saved. On rebooting, the scroll axis goes back to the the original settings.

Any idea how I can save the modified configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest automatically running Your command on each system startup:

1. Access startup applications preferences - [Where did the startup-applications-preferences program go?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159887/where-did-the-startup-applications-preferences-program-go) (may be already present at `Unity-Dash`).
2. Then add an entry containing Your command.
3. Since that the configuration should be adjusted on future bootups.

You can also add the command to Your `Unity launcher` at `Ubuntu Tweak` (should be foundable at `Unity-Dash`), I have several commands stored in `Terminal` icon, pretty useful.

---

Still I'm too curios how to make the `xinput` config constant and why it is not remembered by default.

Comment: Okay, I added a T650NaturalScrolling.sh file to the Startup Application Preferences and it survives the boot. Thank you.